# How can I construct std::tuple of references from a parameter pack?

Tags: c++, c++17, variadic-templates, stdtuple

I have a builder class that I'd like to store arguments as references for use in subsequent building.

I'd like to pass in a variable number of arguments to my class, infer the template arguments using class template argument deduction, and store those passed arguments as references in a std::tuple.

What's the easiest way to convert from a parameter pack to a std::tuple of references?

I found std::forward_as_tuple which does something similar to what I want, but I don't want a forwarding reference plus it gives a syntax error during initialization of the member tuple.

```
template <typename... Ts>
struct Builder
{
using ArgsT = decltype(std::forward_as_tuple(Ts{}...));

ArgsT args_;

Builder(Ts&... ts) : args_(ts...) {}
};

int main()
{
    struct Foo
    {
        int a;
        double b;
    };

    Foo foo{};
    Builder fooBuilder{foo.a, foo.b};
}
```

The syntax error is:

> error: no matching function for call to `std::tuple<int&&, double&&>::tuple(int&, double&)`

Comment: Could you show how you intend to use `Builder` after it has been initialized?

Comment: I simplified the Builder for the sake of the question. In actuality, it will take another templated class, and it will receive the arguments in the actual build method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you simply wants reference, use them directly:

```
template <typename... Ts>
struct Builder
{
    using ArgsT = std::tuple<Ts&...>;

    ArgsT args_;

    Builder(Ts&... ts) : args_(ts...) {}
};

int main()
{
    struct Foo
    {
        int a;
        double b;
    };

    Foo foo{};
    Builder fooBuilder{foo.a, foo.b};
}
```

For your code:

`decltype(std::forward_as_tuple(Ts{}...))` resolves in `std::tuple<Ts&&...>`.
`Ts{}` creates a temporary (and requires your type to be default constructible).

And you cannot bind `int&` to `int&&`.

You might use `decltype(std::forward_as_tuple(std::declval<Ts&>()...))` which resolves in `std::tuple<Ts&...>`, but later is simpler and provided solution;-).

Answer (score 2):

Another way:

```
#include <tuple>

template<typename Tuple>                                                                                                    
struct Builder                                                                                                      
{                                                                                                                            
    Tuple args_;                                                                                            
    Builder(Tuple const& t) : args_(t) {}                                                                    
};

int main()                                                                                                                   
{                                                                                                                            
    struct Foo                                                                                                               
    {                                                                                                                        
        int a;                                                                                                               
        double b;                                                                                                            
    };                                                                                                                       

    Foo foo{};                                                                                                               
    Builder fooBuilder{std::tie(foo.a, foo.b)};                                                                               
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`Builder(Ts&... ts)` is a pack of lvalue references.

`Ts{}...` is a pack of prvalues of the same type.

`std::forward_as_tuple(Ts{}...)` is a tuple containing rvalue references to the same type.

lvalue references and rvalue references are not the same thing; you cannot assign one to the other.  So `args_(ts...)` generates the appropriate error message.

There is more than one way to produce a solution to what could be your problem.

```
template <typename... Ts>
struct Builder
{
  using ArgsT = std::tuple<Ts&&...>; // (1)
  using ArgsT = std::tuple<Ts&...>;  // (2)
  using ArgsT = std::tuple<Ts...>;   // (3)
```

all 3 of these are actually reasonable ways to solve your problem, depending on later code options.  Pick one depending on what your real problem is.

```
  ArgsT args_;
```

What goes here:

```
  Builder(Ts&&... ts) : args_(std::forward<Ts>(ts)...) {}
  Builder(Ts&... ts) : args_(ts...) {}
  Builder(Ts&&... ts) : args_(std::forward<Ts>(ts)...) {}
```

for each of the above 3 cases.

In case (1) you perfect forward your arguments into a tuple, and the tuple stores rvalue references to any rvalue arguments.  In case (2) you only take lvalue arguments, and you store a tuple of lvalue references to them.  In case (3) you perfect forward your arguments into a tuple, and store values if the argument was an rvalue and lvalue references it he value was an lvalue.

(3) is useful when you want your references to outlive the current line; the only safe way to do that is to store a copy, and then move into it.

(2) is useful if you only want to refer to lvalues.

(1) is useful if your Builder object is not going to outlive the current line, and you don't want to pay for even moving objects.  It is a tad more dangerous than (1).

All 3 will make your sample code compile.